# Ecto query to also include records with no has_many associated records?

Tags: postgresql, elixir, ecto, has-many

I wrote this query to find all records that are not in Florida.

```
query =
  from papa in Papa,
    inner_join: account in assoc(papa, :account),
    inner_join: location in assoc(account, :locations),
    where: account.email == ^"myapp@example.com",
    where: papa.status == ^"active",
    where: location.papa_id == papa.id, <--- Some of these Papas have ZERO locations.
    where: location.state != ^"FL",
    group_by: [papa.id, location.state, account.id],
    distinct: [papa.id],
    select: [
      papa.id,
      papa.member_id,
      papa.full_name,
      account.id,
      account.full_name,
      location.state,
      papa.status
    ]
```

It's returning correctly all the Papa records with no locations in Florida. Unfortunately it's skipping the Papa records that have literally NO location records.

How can I also include these records in my Ecto query?

Answer (score 2):

Once you have

```rb
inner_join: location in assoc(account, :locations),
```

the `where` clause

```rb
where: location.papa_id == papa.id
```

is redundant, since it’s implied by joining an `assoc`. If you want to include *all* the records from `papas`, you need to use [`left_join`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.html#join/5) (See the diagram [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) for the visualization of what is returned for different joins.)

So, get rid of `where: location.papa_id == papa.id` and change join clause for `location` to:

```rb
left_join: location in assoc(account, :locations),
```